# Как сделать фильтрацию строк при импортировании из excel в БД?

Tags: excel

В Excel имеется таблица, в этой таблице местами повторяются строки, т.е. сходство строк. Задача такова: нужно, чтобы при импортировании в базу данных, происходила фильтрация повторяющихся строк и записывалась одна строка. Сам скрипт конвертирования я написал из excel в бд, а вот с фильтрацией проблема. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Создаете массив[кол-во записей в excel], далее при записи строчки смотрите в массив[№ строчка], если не 1, то записываете, в цикле проверяете все следующие на повторяемость, если да, то запиливаете 1 в массив[строчка повторения]. Идея понятна?

Comment: Идея понятна. Большое спасибо, в принципе, меня идея такая посещала, если можно для наглядности небольшой отрывок примера. С уважением, Alex.

Answer (score 1):

Накидал код по быстрому, но с использованием [Dictionary](http://perfect-excel.ru/publ/excel/makrosy_i_programmy_vba/ischerpyvajushhee_opisanie_obekta_dictionary/7-1-0-101):

```
Dim dictionaryDouble

Public Sub test()
    Set dictionaryDouble = Nothing
    Set dictionaryDouble = New dictionary
    Dim testArray: testArray = Array(Array("1", "1"), Array("1", "2"),     Array("1", "3"), Array("1", "1"), Array("1", "5"), Array("1",     "7"), Array("1", "2"))
    Dim a As Integer
    For a = LBound(testArray) To UBound(testArray)
        Dim val1 As String
        val1 = testArray(a)(0)
        Dim val2 As String
        val2 = testArray(a)(1)
        Dim key As String
        key = val1 & val2
        Dim isDouble As Boolean
        isDouble = checkDouble(key)
        Debug.Print "key: " & key & " is double: " & isDouble
    Next a
End Sub

Private Function checkDouble(key As String) As Boolean
    Dim exists As Boolean
    exists = dictionaryDouble.exists(key)
    If Not exists Then
        dictionaryDouble.Add key, ""
    End If
    checkDouble = exists
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

проще всего создать уникальный индекс в бд